# How to have text already in the input and off when on focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

Please check out the jsfiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/H49EC/1/

As you can see it is two search boxes with a button below it. How can I have it so text is in each box but when each box is clicked the text disappears?

Also if the box is clicked but nothing is entered the text reappears.

Thanks guys, I have been searching but I am unsure of what this is called or what language needs to be used.

Thanks again!

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use placeholder attribute on your inputs.

```
<input type='text' placeholder='whatever' />
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you're using HTML5 you can use the new `placeholder=""` attribute:

```
placeholder="Your text here"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H49EC/2/

---

If you're not using HTML5, you can use jQuery to change the value: (for older browsers and IE)

```
$('input').focus(function(){        
            // on focus if the value of the field is still the initial then clear it        
            if ( (this.value) == this.defaultValue ) this.value = '';    }).blur(function(){        
            // on blur if the value is still cleared then restore the initial        
            if ( (this.value) == '' )   this.value = this.defaultValue;    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H49EC/7/

Comment: Thanks i didn't realise it could be so simple!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support older browsers and can't use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, you will need to use JavaScript. Something along these lines should get you started:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input1");
input.onfocus = function() {
    if(this.value === "Default") {
        this.value = "";  
    }
};
input.onblur = function() {
    if(this.value === "") {
        this.value = "Default"; 
    }  
};
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H49EC/5/) to show you how it works. Note that I've added an `id` to the `input` element so it can be accessed with `getElementById`. If you want to apply this to multiple input elements, you may want to generalise it instead of applying it to just the one element.

Comment: I would rather rely on the `defaultValue` instead of hard coding the default text - it's much more versatile that way.

Answer (score 0):

I used [infieldlabel](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) to accomplish this on a page once and it worked well. Hoever, it is a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

do u mean placeholder?
http://jsfiddle.net/H49EC/4/

Answer (score 0):

This link offers support on the placeholder attribute.

Its not completely cross browser compliant at the moment, IE is the main issue.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css

For IE people are making divs above them and when you click it hides. There are plenty of options on google by typing in placeholder :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is what you're looking for.

```
<input type="text" name="searchText" placeholder="Search Here!" />
```

See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) for information regarding the placeholder attribute.

And [here's a quick jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/uupqD/1/).